# I am encountering module loading problem in mysql

Tags: mysql

I will work with mysql, but it gives this error anyway. I did delete the module but it did not change, I loaded it differently, I could not solve the modules.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\INAL\Desktop\Son Scriptler\mysql\mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "C:\Users\INAL\Desktop\Son Scriptler\mysql\mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
```

Comment: If you add your code, it would ease others to provide helps. Please also check [ask] and [example]

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the `mysql-connector` did you try installing it using pip?

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

Comment: The problem was that my project name was mysql.py and I solved the problem by changing the project name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my project name was mysql.py and I solved the problem by changing the project name.